# Flash parameters are prepending the controller on the URL and cannot find files to play

Tags: flash, model-view-controller

I have an embedded flash object with a movie parameter that uses a url as a parameter. When this URL is resolved on the client the full friendly url is used and the link to the .swf is then incorrect.

Here is the HTML:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
 codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
 width="100" height="30" id="MyId" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="Content/MyApp.swf?parm='/sounddir/mysound.mp3'" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<embed src="/Content/MyApp.swf?parm='/sounddir/mysound.mp3'" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100"
height="30" name="MyApp" align="middle"
allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

What happens is the url (for example) http://www.domain.com/MyContoller/MyAction?someid=4
the value for the movie parms winds up with:

MyContoller/'/sounddir/mysound.mp3'

I tried every combination of Url.Content, ResolveUrl etc. but that all happens on the server and is no help on the client. I also tried to figure out how to do something with the route maps, but no success there...I can't even get rid of the "'/" in the middle of the incorrect URL...

Sure would appreciate help on this...any good blogs out there on how to use flash with MVC 2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give an exact answer, but a couple of things to look in to are:

Are you sure the swf expects the parm with the quotes? It is more common to send URL parameters like that without quotes, like "/Content/MyApp.swf?parm=/sounddir/mysound.mp3".

An alternative to appending the parameter in the URL of the swf file is using [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html). The ActionScript in the Flash doesn't need to be altered if you switch from appending the parameter to the swf URL to using flashvars, it will retrieve the value the same way internally.